# Is it feasible/possible to use refraction for x-ray spectrum analysis?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, refraction, spectroscopy, x-rays

In [x-ray spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_spectroscopy) [Bragg reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law) off of a crystal is used for spectral analysis. In [x-ray diffraction](http://pruffle.mit.edu/atomiccontrol/education/xray/xray_diff.php) the same principle is used for monochromatizing the x-ray beam from an x-ray tube. For visible light, however, an [optical prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism) is used to decompose the spectrum. I understand that Bragg scattering would not be feasible for visible light as the wavelength range of visible light ([390-700nm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum) vs. [0.01-10nm for x-ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray)) is much larger than [atomic spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_spacing) in most crystals (a few angstroms), and the Bragg angle has to be very shallow(?).

Is it feasible to use a prism instead of Bragg reflection in x-ray spectral analysis (i.e., is there a material with low x-ray attenuation and suitable refraction index)? Is there any table of refraction indices for different materials at various wavelengths (alternatively, a table of relative permittivity and relative permeability)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is http://henke.lbl.gov/optical_constants/

But no, prisms are not suitable for x-rays: dispersion is small, there will always be absorption. And there are anomalous effects near absorption edges.

Comment: As a numerical example, aluminum has an index of refraction of 1.000008 for x-rays with a wavelength $1.6\times 10^{-10}$ m.

Comment: @BenCrowell Generally in the x-ray region, $n$ is slightly less than unity.  (Except near absorption edges.) For example, holes in aluminum can be used as positive lenses http://spie.org/newsroom/3688-refractive-lenses-allow-compact-precision-focusing-of-x-rays?SSO=1